# How to Build Docker-compose file for multiple containers

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I have two different containers (1. Frontend app, 2. Webserver ) 1st dependent on server.
Currently both containers are built using seperate docker files and running perfectly fine in localhost envionment. Application is built using nodejs and angular.
I am using docker desktop for windows server 2019.

Using user defined network for both containers to communicate with each other:

docker network create --driver bridge dev_network

I need to build a docker compose file for both of them but don't have enough knowledge on how to build a working compose file. Will be glad if anyone could help me for the same.

Thanks for your time!

**Frontend docker file:**

```
FROM node:latest as build
WORKDIR /usr/local/app
COPY ./ /usr/local/app/
RUN npm install
FROM nginx:latest
COPY --from=build /usr/local/app/dist/ClientPortal /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
```

**WebServer dockerfile:**

```
FROM node:14-alpine
ENV NODE_ENV=production
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY ["package.json", "package-lock.json*", "npm-shrinkwrap.json*", "./"]
RUN npm install --production --silent && mv node_modules ../
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000 8600
CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

I tried with following compose file
Defined volume to a windows drive as server image folders along with docker file is located into the directory.

Issue is i docker-compose build is building both the images but when i fire the up command the server container fails to load and exits with exit code 1

Error message: Error: Cannot find module '/usr/src/app/server.js'

**Docker-Compose file:**

```
version: '3.4'
services: 
  clientportal:
    image: clientportal
    container_name: cspfrontend
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: production
    networks: 
      - dev_network
    ports:
      - 80:80
  
  clientportalserver:
    image: clientportalserver
    container_name: cspserver
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: E:\Work\ClientPortalServer/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - E:\Work\ClientPortalServer
    networks: 
      - dev_network
    ports:
     - 3000:3000  
networks: 
  dev_network:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? There are many docker compose examples and tutorials available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with something like this in a docker-compose.yml in the root folder:

```
version: "3"
services:
  frontend:
    build: ./frontend
    ports:
    - 80:80
    networks:
    - dev_network
    depends_on:
    - backend
  backend:
    build: ./backend
    ports:
    - 3000:3000
    expose:
    - "3000"
    - "8600"
    networks:
    - dev_network
    
networks:
  dev_network:
    driver: bridge
```

This requires you to have a frontend and a backend folder to your projects, and in those folder you have to have those Dockerfiles, that you showed. I don't know what port are you using in your backend project, so I guessed with port 3000.

```
project root
│   docker-compose.yml 
│
└───frontend
│   │   Dockerfile
│   │   ...
│   
└───backend
    │   Dockerfile
    │   ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts! much appreciated. But don't i have to define volume path (windows path)? to let docker compose know about the location of folder of other container files?

Comment: Can you describe your question a bit more, I don't really understand your problem. The example above is doing two things, builds the given folders Dockerfile, and runs it in a container. The frontend and backend containers "see" each other, because they are in the same network. You don't have to have volumes, because you defined everything in your Dockerfile.

Comment: I meant to say I have two different folders for frontend and server images in windows so how will my compose file know where is the other dockerfile located. I tried with a compose file ,can you please take a look at it?. Requirement is we have to keep server and frontend files separately.

Comment: It's relative to the docker-compose.yml file, for example if you put the .yml in your frontend folder, you can specify the build path relative to the frontend projects folder: build: ../backend

Comment: Hi Mate, Thank you for your efforts for sharing the docker-compose file with me. With little modifications i was able to start both backend and frontend containers and get  the desired output on localhost. I was struggling with docker-compose build issue for a while and your explanation really helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You should start by reading the documentation on the website.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/

The first page shows a working example of a simple compose file with a `web` service and `redis` service. If you managed to get the containers running, then the options found in the [Compose file reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/) will be very familiar to you.

You may find this link of particular interest in regards to using an existing Docker network:

https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#use-a-pre-existing-network

Comment: Please do not use link-only-answers. If the link(s) die, the value of your answer diminshes. It is considered better, to literally write an answer and use links as references. Imagine ou would be the one asking and then decide if your answer solves the problem _without_ the links.

Comment: I appreciate that logic, is it preferable to simply copy and paste from the original docker articles as examples? I hardly wanted to type out a solution for the user given no effort had been shown that they'd reasonably attempted to solve the issue they posted about

Comment: I guess that is a question of personal choice.  Not putting in effort in an answer, because the OP didnt put effort in the question is kind of ... not leading by example. If you think, the question has not enough effort been put it, you can decide not to answer, instead of answering in a suboptimal way. But if you decide to answer, try to answer th question in the best possible way and format.

Comment: That's a fair statement. But what should one do when the question is open ended and requires more information that can be reasonably condensed? I believe in this scenario, where the question roughly translates to "I don't have enough knowledge, help me learn", then pointing the user to available resources is probably the most helpful thing. If we're talking about helpful responses, are they necessary when this question is not a helpful one in itself, and will likely not help further users? All food for thought, but I'll endeavour to include more in my answers in future

Comment: In that case, there is a flag to raise: "needs more detail / focus / clarity".

Comment: Flagging a question and not providing the user any resources to pursue is perhaps the most effective way to dimish value from an answer, by not providing one in the first place